# How Is a Signal Changed After Sampling?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, sampling, frequency

I can't understand sampling signal mathematically.

for example $x(t) = 2\cos(100\pi t) + \cos(300\pi t)$ and I know I should use sampling frequency $300\textrm{Hz}$ to sample this signal.

and after sampling, what is done?

How is $x(t)$ changed? and what frequency does sampled $x(t)$ have?

Comment: To be precise, a sampling frequency *strictly greater than* 300Hz should be used.

Comment: Could you please mark an answer?

Answer (score 3):

This is to explain what actually sampling is and why and how it's done.

Here I've generated a simple continuous-like sinusoidal signal with frequency fm = 10kHz. In order to make it appear as a continuous signal when plotting, a sampling rate of fs=500kHz is used

[image: Simple continuous sinusodial signal]

Pretending the above-generated signal as a “continuous” signal, we would like to convert the signal to the discrete-time equivalent by sampling. By Nyquist Shannon Theorem, the signal has to be sampled at at-least fs=2*fm=20 kHz. Let’s sample the signal at f{s1}=30kHz and then at f{s1}=50kHz for illustration.

[image: After sampling with different frequencies]

CODE

```
fs=500e3; %Very high sampling rate 500 kHz
f=10e3; %Frequency of sinusoid
nCyl=5; %generate five cycles of sinusoid
t=0:1/fs:nCyl*1/f; %time index
x=cos(2*pi*f*t);

plot(t,x)
title('Continuous sinusoidal signal');
xlabel('Time(s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
```

For Sampling-

```
fs1=30e3; %30kHz sampling rate
t1=0:1/fs1:nCyl*1/f; %time index
x1=cos(2*pi*f*t1);

fs2=50e3; %50kHz sampling rate
t2=0:1/fs2:nCyl*1/f; %time index
x2=cos(2*pi*f*t2);

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,x);
hold on;
stem(t1,x1);
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,x);
hold on;
stem(t2,x2);
```

Answer (score 1):

> and after sampling, what is done?

Well, nothing special, you're just getting another signal in a discrete time domain, based on your original signal in a continual domain.

Answer (score 0):

First pay attention that the [Nyquist Shannon Sampling Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) requires 
sampling at rate which is strictly larger than twice (Though it is for edge cases, yet this is the accurate theorem).

Sampling is 1 step to get signals to be Discrete, which means we can store them in a digital form.
Sampling is the [discretization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization) of the Time Axis and we need to apply [Quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing)) which is discretization of the Value Axis.

Sampling Theorem states that given a sampled signal (Which is a set of the signal values at discretized grid of time samples) what are the cases it can be fully reconstructed given a single property of the signal - Band Limited Signal.

So what's changed?
You don't have the whole signal but only set of samples from it on a time grid.